# combineLatest is fired only for first event

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, combinelatest

I have 3 events which I want to combine, and when one of them is fired,  to call the service. I used `combineLatest`, but it works only if the first event is fired by the `filterChanged`.

`filterChanged` is an local event, while the rest are events comed from the child component. How can I fix this, to emit one of the events, even from the page initialization?

```
filterChanged = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
paginatorChanged = new EventEmitter<MatPaginator>();
sortChanged = new EventEmitter<{}>();

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
   combineLatest(
      this.paginatorChanged,
      this.sortChanged,
      this.filterChanged
   ).pipe(
      startWith([null, null, null]),
      switchMap(value => {
      const paginator = value[0];
      const sort = value[1];
      const filters = value[2];
    
      return this.service.getFiltered(paginator, sort, filters);
   })).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}    

applyFilter(): void {
  this.filterChanged.emit(true);
}

onPaginatorChanged(paginator): void {
  this.paginatorChanged.emit(paginator);
}

onSortChanged(sort): void {
  this.sortChanged.emit(sort);
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question isn't clear at the moment, but if you wish to trigger the `combineLatest` *without* the `filterChanged` observable emitting at least once, then I'd say you're using the `startWith` operator wrong. It should be piped to each source observable individually.

Try the following

```js
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  combineLatest(
    this.paginatorChanged.pipe(startWith(null)),
    this.sortChanged.pipe(startWith(null)),
    this.filterChanged.pipe(startWith(null))
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
    const paginator = value[0];
    const sort = value[1];
    const filters = value[2];
  
    return this.service.getFiltered(paginator, sort, filters);
    })
  ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
}
```

Also for local multicast observables you could use RxJS `Subject` (or it's siblings) instead of using Angular specific `EventEmitter`.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I tought I can use startWith() for all the events result, but was needed to specify it for each. This is a refactor, after the removing of all filters, sort and paginators from the smart component, I'll change the Events with Subject (inside a service, or even ngrx selectors (because is already used in the app)). Thanks a lot